# Pygame: Player won't move when key is held down

Tags: python, pygame

Just starting out in pygame and trying to get a simple dot to move around the screen when you hold down the arrow keys. Currently, it only moves when you press the key, but you'd have to repeatedly press it.

```
import random
import pygame
import keyboard
import time
from pygame.locals import *

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 150
        self.y = 150

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Smile, you're beautiful!")
player = Player()
while True:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.x += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.y += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.x -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.y -= 5
        pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (180, 180, 180), (player.x, player.y), 5)
```

Also, I'd appreciate any tips you might have regarding my current code that may be improved upon or changed to make more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) rather than the key down events. This way you know which keys are currently being pressed on every tick

```
while True:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.x += 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.y += 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.x -= 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.y -= 5
```